# Node.js gives 404 error in production with React on Windows Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure

I use MS Azure to host a site where I have a React app served by Node. Inside React there are Routes for navigation.
In development if I go directly to *localhost:5000/user* it renders the right page, but in production going to */user* it gives a 404 error.

Here's my Node code:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path');
const userRouter = require('./routers/userRouter')
const dataRouter = require('./routers/dataRouter')
const keys = require('./config/keys')

const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000


app.use(express.json())
app.use('/node/user',userRouter)
app.use('/node/data',dataRouter)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../../', 'build/index.html'));
});
```

I thought its due to /user route not being pointed at react but isnt that what app.get('/*'...) is for?

Any advice on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`app.get(/*)` does not work. Consequently, you can use below code:

```
app.get('/:op',function(req,res)
{
    if(String(req.params.op).equals("user"))
    {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../../', 'build/index.html'));
    }
    else
    {
        res.send("I am Foo");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. It was the '../../ which was looking for the build folder outside the src directory.
Rewriting it as below solved the issue

```
res.sendFIle(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'));
```